# Automatic Program Restart?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been wondering if there is a way to potentially "restart" a python program from the script. Say if I wanted to make a program write itself as it ran, but I would need a way for it to restart itself after It's changed itself. Any insights on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the current process with the new one, you can do that by calling `os.execv`, or similar function. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv for the details.

To reexecute self, it's likely:

```
import os
import sys
os.execl(*sys.argv)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This really helped!